# SQLGrammarException using Hibernate with Postgresql

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql

I am using hibernate with Postgresql to do a demo project. But I get weird exception now.
I have 2 simple tables, where one is referenced by the other. Here is the create statements:

```
CREATE TABLE minishopping_schema.Category (
    id          SERIAL      PRIMARY KEY,
    name        VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    descrip     TEXT        NOT NULL,
    products    INT         NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
CREATE TABLE minishopping_schema.Product (
    id          SERIAL      PRIMARY KEY,
    name        VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    SKU         TEXT        NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    cid         INT         REFERENCES minishopping_schema.Category (id) NOT NULL,
    price       MONEY       NOT NULL
)
```

When I try to insert a record into the Product table I received

```
Hibernate: insert into minishopping_schema.product (cid, name, sku, price) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [DBModel.Product]
```

Hibernate generated an object of `Product(category, name, sky, price)`, and I checked before insertion that every attribute is legal. And I can successfully insert tuples to the table in sql editor. Could anyone help?

Comment: Can you please post Hiberate Entity classes for both Product and Category?

Comment: Can you show the **full** exception? There must be some Postgres exception (including the *real* error message) somewhere in the stacktrace of the Hibernate exception

Comment: you emight need a deferrable foreign key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Hibernate does not support type "money" although it will be generated as double when doing Hibernate reverse engineering. It is really annoying.